# Pass parameters dynamically to stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, db2, mule

I am trying to pass values dynamically to the following stored procedure in db2,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30), IN ExceptionId1 Integer, IN EventSource1 VARCHAR(30) ) 
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        select CreationTime 
        from Exception_Message 
        where (SourceQueue=SourceQueue1 or ExceptionId=ExceptionId1 or EventSource=EventSource1); 
    open c1; 
END;
```

I have created this stored procedure in IBM Data Studio 3.1.
Here I am trying to pass parameters dynamically to the values SourceQueue1, ExceptionId1 or EventSource1. My requirement is that the procedure should work when at least one of the above parameters is passed. If only two parameters are passed it should search for both the parameters and retrieve the data. Could anyone please give me an idea to resolve this.
I am trying to call this through Mule database connector.

Comment: Multiple optional parameters usually means dynamic SQL.  Is that not an option for some reason?  You'd still want to prepare it as parameterized to avoid SQL Injection, but only three parameters would be pretty easy to write (especially like this).

Answer (score 0):

SQL procedures can be overloaded.  Make a procedure with the same name and different parameters.  Then depending on how you call the procedure the correct procedure by name and parms is called.

Example overloaded one parm procedure for exceptionid.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN ExceptionId1 Integer ) 
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        select CreationTime 
        from Exception_Message 
        where (ExceptionId=ExceptionId1); 
    open c1; 
END;
```

Comment: Hi Danny, Thank you. I have the following doubts. Will this work for DB2 as well? In case if it works then do I need to remove the REPLACE from the procedure and overload it?

Comment: In DB2 overloaded stored procedures are resolved by the number of parameters, but not their types (or names). In other words, it would be impossible to determine which of the three possible variants of `E_Enquiry(?)` to call.

Comment: And even then, two of the parameters have the same types anyways, so would be ambiguous regardless.

Comment: @mustaccio I did not know db2 overloaded procedures are by parm count.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the overloading answer @danny117 provided...

Depending on the platform and version of DB2 you are using, you may be able to assign defaults for parameters not passed.

Using DB2 for IBM i 7.1 TR5 or higher, you'd do the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL
     , IN ExceptionId1 Integer DEFAULT NULL
     , IN EventSource1 VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL)
```

The when invoking, you'd use named parameters like so:

```
CALL E_ENQUIRY(ExceptionId1=>0201);
```

Comment: Hi Charles,  On adding DEFAULT NULL, I could see is that it is checking for the null values in the database. But what I want is that, if I pass value for SourceQueue1 and ExceptionId1 alone, then it should check for both these values and omit the EventSource1. But if I give as DEFAULT NULL it is checking for null values for EventSource1 as well. Please assist me on this.

Comment: It shouldn't be.  `WHERE COL1 = MYVAL` will not be true even if both values are NULL.  Besides, you're ORing the tests.  Perhaps you want the `WHERE` clause from @mustaccio answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification of the cursor's `WHERE` clause should do the trick:

```
where 
 (SourceQueue=SourceQueue1 or SourceQueue1 is null) and 
 (ExceptionId=ExceptionId1 or ExceptionId1 is null) and 
 (EventSource=EventSource1 or EventSource1 is null)
```

Comment: As I read it, the OP wants to be able to `CALL E_Enquiry('SOMEVAL')`, so he's going to need to either overload the name or use default parms if available.